# Erro em obter o valor do banco

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando pegar o ID de um dado do banco com PHP. Na hora de retornar o valor, ele sempre vem como 1.

```
//Obtenho os valores por GET
$description = $_GET['DESC'];
$contentType = $_GET['TYPE'];
$content = $_GET['CONT'];

//Crio meu objeto de acesso ao banco e realizo a query
$dao = new DAO();
$result = $dao->select("SELECT ID_PUBLICATION FROM TB_PUBLICACOES_E_EVENTOS WHERE TXT_DESCRIPTION = :description AND TXT_TYPE = :contentType AND TXT_CONTENT = :content", Array(":description"=>$description, ":contentType"=>$contentType, ":content"=>$content));

//Atribuo o retorno (array) para um int 
$id_publication = (int) $result;

//Exibo os dois valores na tela
var_dump($id_publication);
var_dump($result);
```

O resultado aparece assim para mim:

```
int(1)
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["ID_PUBLICATION"]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
}
```

Pelo que entendi, ele está retornando a quantidade de posições do array e atribuindo o valor ao meu `$id_publication`, por isso está sempre 1.

É possível acessar esse valor que é retornado do banco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result` é um array retornado por um `fetchAll()` dessa forma ele sempre vem com indíce zero. A forma correta de acessar é:

```
$result[0]['ID_PUBLICATION'];
```

Comment: Uau, foi rápido! hahaha. Obrigado @rray, é isso mesmo que estava errado! Preciso esperar 8 minutos para marcar como resposta.

Comment: @Csorgo Está usando o PDO? Quando for retornar apenas um registros use o `fetch()` assim você acessa o valor direto (sem o indíce zero)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! Vou adaptar meu código.